# autoreconf -i -f requires missing files

Tags: raspberry-pi, autoreconf

I'm running Shairport Sync, an AirPlay audio player for Linux and FreeBSD, on a Raspberry Pi 3. That's all working fine. Shairport doesn't read metadata on its own, and to do that I am trying to install Shairport Sync Metadata Reader (https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync-metadata-reader). I've cloned then repo from git, and then run

```
autoreconf -i -f
```

This returns the error:

```
autoreconf: 'configure.ca' or 'configure.in' is required
```

I've looked around for this error, but everything I've found hasn't helped. I made sure automake, autoconf, autotools, and libtool are installed. I installed pkgconf as well, but that didn't work.

Any idea what these files are, and where they belong?

Comment: Doesn't look like a `git` question.

Comment: The repo comes from github. Does that not count?

Comment: nope.... you cloned fine.... git is not involved.

Comment: I'll remove it.